# MDX - 3rd + dimension example needed

Tags: ssas, mdx

I am trying to learn MDX.  I am an experienced SQL Developer.

I am trying to find an example of an MDX query that has more than two dimensions.  Every single webpage that talks about MDX provides simple two dimensional examples link this:

```
select 
{[Measures].[Sales Amount]} on columns,
Customer.fullname.members on rows
from [Adventure Works DW2012]
```

I am looking for examples that use the following aliases: PAGES (third dimension?), section (forth dimension?) and Chapter (fifth dimension?).  I have tried this but I do not think it is correct:

```
select 
{[Measures].[Sales Amount]} on columns,
Customer.fullname.members on rows,
customer.Location.[Customer Geography] as pages
from [Adventure Works DW2012]
```

I am trying to get this output using an MDX query (this is from AdventureWorks DW2012):

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not a 3-dimensional resultset in your screenshot, unless there's something cropped from it.

Something like

```
SELECT [Geography].[Country].Members ON 0,
[Customer].[CustomerName].Members ON 1
FROM [whatever the cube is called]
WHERE [Measures].[Sales Amount]
```

(dimension/hierarchy/level names may not be exactly right)
would give a resultset like the one in your message.

The beyond 2nd-dimension dimensions and dimension names are not used in any client tool that I know.  (Others may know different).  They seem to be there in MDX so that MDX can hand >2-dimensional resultsets to clients that can handle them (e.g. an MDX subquery handing its results to the main query).

An often-used trick in MDX is to get the members of two dimensions onto one axis by cross-joining:

SELECT
{[Date].[Calendar Date].[Calendar Year].Members * [Geography].[Country].Members} ON 0,
[something else] ON 1
FROM [Cube]

Comment: OK thanks.  What is the point of multi dimensional modelling if client tools cannot handle it?

Comment: Good question.  The point of MD modelling is that it makes working with the data very flexible, either within query code (as in whytheq's subquery example below), or on the client interface itself.  You can't actually get a 3-dimensional resultset, but you can choose to combine any dimensions on axes, plus any number as slicers.

Comment: I believe Excel is capable of showing a three dimensional + resultset (see the screenshot in my original post).  Is that correct?

Comment: That looks 2-dimensional to me, in the "normal" sense (it's displayed on a 2-d surface).  If you can get a 3D display in Excel, let me know what version you're running! ;)   You have the Geography and Customer dimensions on axes, one member of the Measures dimension (Sales amount) in the values area.  You could add more Measures to the values area, but it ends up very messy-looking.  You can also slice (aka filter) on any number of dimensions, including multi-selecting.  It's still a representation of multiple dimensions in 2D, though.

Comment: The way that I understand it is that Excel is capable of displaying three dimensional models as a flat structure (it allows you to drill down into the dimensions).  Is that right or am I missing something? Thanks for continuing to answer my questions +1 (for the answer).

Comment: Yes, Excel shows a "flattened" view on a multi-dimensional structure.  Don't get confused by the hierarchical drill-down capabilities: a hierarchy is not a multi-dimensional structure, but a structure *within* one dimension.  Originally in SSAS each dimension was allowed just one hierarchy.  Actually thinking of dimensions as completely flat structures (like lists), forgetting about hierarchies for a moment, makes the whole thing much easier to understand.  Then you can turn to hierarchies, as a refinement of a simple, flat, list-like dimension.

Comment: I'd add that the Adventureworks tutorial, while useful, actually obscures some of the basics of MD modelling, by being flashy and showing off what it can do, skipping past the basic concepts.  SSAS overuses wizards for dimension/measuregroup creation, IMHO.  You might get a better introduction by creating some simple tables of your own (Customer, Town, Sale etc) and building a cube from nothing.

Comment: +1 for the reference to hierarchies, which has helped.  I guess that if a pivot table references three dimensions e.f. Customer, Product and Location, then it is three dimensional? - even though it is displayed in a flat structure.  The hierarchies allow you do drill down into the dimensions.  Is that right?

Comment: That's exactly it.  This site: http://www.kimballgroup.com/ has an enormous amount of free theoretical resources, from the very basics to highly advanced stuff I've never touched.

Answer (score 3):

How about the following - it does not send more than two dimensions back to a flat screen but it uses quite a few dimensions **explicitly**:

```
SELECT 
  [Measures].[Sales Amount] ON O,
  [Customer].[fullname].MEMBERS ON 1
FROM
( 
  SELECT
    [Date].[Calendar Month].[Calendar Month].&[February-2012] ON 0,
    [Geography].[Country].[Country].&[Canada] ON 1,
    [Product].[Product].&[Red Bike] ON 2,
    [Customer].[Customer].&[foo bar] ON 3
  FROM [Adventure Works DW2012]
)
```

I've made up the dimension | hierarchy | member combinations as I do not have access to the cube.

Also if we consider **implicit** dimensions then take the following:

```
SELECT 
  [Customer].[Location].[Customer Geography]  ON 0,
  [Customer].[fullname].[fullname].&[Aaron Flores] ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works DW2012]
WHERE 
  (
   [Measures].[Sales Amount]
  );
```

On the slicer I've used braces `(..)` which indicate a `tuple`, but this is actually shorthand for the following:

```
SELECT 
  [Customer].[Location].[Customer Geography]  ON 0,
  [Customer].[fullname].[fullname].&[Aaron Flores] ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works DW2012]
WHERE 
  (
   [Measures].[Sales Amount]
  ,[Date].[Calendar Month].[Calendar Month].[All],
  ,[Geography].[Country].[Country].[All],
  ,[Product].[Product].[All]
  ,...
  ,...
  ....
  );
```

The `All` member from every dimension in the cube could be included in this slicer without affecting the result.

So the whole nature of mdx is multi-dimensional - yes you do not get more than a 2 dimensional table returned to your screen but the way you get to that cellset could well involve many dimensions.

Comment: Are multi dimensional structures used in client applications or are they only used to optimise storage? I believe Excels Pivot Table allows a user to see a multi dimensional data structure, however I could be wrong - I am new to this.  Am I right? +1 for the examples.  I will try them tomorrow.

Comment: Excel pivot tables were created at the same time as olap - I believe they both use the same technology, in other words when a pivot table is just a bog standard pivot table it is using multi-dimensional technology in the back ground. Connecting excel pivots to full multi-dimensional cubes is a standard way to access cubes - this has been available in Excel for more than 10 years.

Comment: Thanks.  Is the screenshot in my original post a three dimensional display?

Comment: I suppose as long as we have numbers (measures) that are affected by several categories (dimensions) then we are in a multidimensional context...so yes the screenshot is a flat table but it is still an example of multidimensional data (1 measure and 2 dimensions being visible but many other dimensions being implied)