# 3+ dimensional MDX statement

Tags: sql-server, ssas, mdx

I am an experienced SQL Developer trying to learn MDX in my spare time.  I understand how to deploy a cube and write a two dimensional query.  I am now trying to write a three dimensional query.  I have deployed a cube with multiple dimensions as shown below (and inspired by this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ctUiHZHr-5M):

[image]

I am trying to create an MDX that uses three dimensions in a derived table.  In a previous question here: [MDX - 3rd + dimension example needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37119946/mdx-3rd-dimension-example-needed) whytheq provides examples, however they error.

I cannot find a single tutorial online, which talks about how to use more than two dimensions e.g. pages; sections etc.  Every single tutorial I have read and every single example in the book I bought uses simple two dimensional examples.  Hence the question to try and get started.

For example, I have tried this:

```
   SELECT 
   [full name] ON 0,
   measures.amount ON 1 
FROM(
  SELECT 
    customer.[full name].members on 0,
    salesman.[id].members on 1,
    [Measures].[Amount] on 2
  FROM [Analysis Services Test]
);
```

The error is: "Query (3, 10) Parser: The syntax for 'id' is incorrect."

**Update** @mxix states that Excel pivot tables are only capable of displaying two dimensions.  Is this not an example of a three dimensional pivot table (it has dimensions for: Salesman; Customer and Car)?

[image]

Comment: Could you add the queries that you tried and the errors?

Comment: The answer is so simple, I'm thinking there must be some aspect to your question that you haven't told us clearly enough.   Please show us what you tried and what error you got.  What error did you get when you tried WhyTheQ's example?

Comment: @Tab Alleman, I have updated the question.  I am very new to this.  I am just trying to see a multi dimensional MDX query that compiles.

Comment: And what error are you getting from this query?

Comment: @Tab Alleman, I have updated the question with the error.

Comment: ` whytheq provides examples, however they error.` I would fall of my chair if they did **not** error as I just made up the hierarchy and member names to create examples to show you possible structures...

Comment: Expand the tree under Salesman, and if there is a Members node under it, drag that onto your query instead of `salesman.id.members`   In fact, I suggest that you always drag and drop nodes into your queries instead of typing them free-hand.

Comment: @whytheq, I understand that.  I did not post a screenshot of the cube in my previous question.  In highnsight I should of done.

Comment: why are you worried about pages and sections? there is a good reason you cannot find much about them - because no one uses them.

Comment: @whythec, because they exist and I figure they must exist for a reason.

Comment: @w0051977 no worries. Most languages have redundant sections. Adding a WHERE clause in a subselect is something else that I remember does not cause an exception, but does nothing.

Comment: If you add an explanation of what you are trying to get with your query maybe we can give you a more accurate example.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this answers your question but I hope it helps.
For the given dimensions you supplied. First I would like to point out, most client applications are only able to show 2 Axis, and that's why most examples focus on 2 axis. SSMS and Excel Pivot tables are some examples of clients that can only show 2 axis. **Columns** and **Rows**.

You can query more Axis but SSMS won't be able to show you, since it can only do tabular representations of Data.

This is a valid MDX query:(but you should get an error on SSMS if you try it)

```
SELECT
    [Car].[Id].MEMBERS ON COLUMNS,
    [Time].[Date].MEMBERS ON ROWS,
    [Salesman].[Id].MEMBERS ON PAGES
FROM [Analysis Services Test]
WHERE
    [Measures].[Amount]
```

But you can `crossjoin(*)` dimension in single axis to get your data from those dimensions in a Valid 2 axis representation.

```
SELECT
    NON EMPTY
    [Car].[Id].MEMBERS ON COLUMNS
    NON EMPTY
    [Time].[Date].MEMBERS *
    [Salesman].[Id].MEMBERS ON ROWS
FROM [Analysis Services Test]
WHERE
    [Measures].[Amount
```

EDIT:

A pivot table has only 2 axis, You have indeed 3 Dimensions represented on 2 Axis, Columns and Rows.
You should not mix the concept of Axis and Dimensions. They are not the same.

There is a cool extension for Excel where you can see the MDX query behind the scenes. https://olappivottableextend.codeplex.com/

You will notice all the queries generated are on 0 (COLUMNS) and 1 (ROWS) Axis.

Comment: I have updated my question with your comment.  Could you take a look?

Comment: the pivot table you've added is very similar to mxix's second script - with the addition of the car dimension as another crossjoin on rows. So it is using 2 main dimensions (rows/columns) and the slicer (the WHERE clause which is sometimes conceptually thought of being the 3rd dimension)

Comment: @mxix - we need one more vote (your vote?) to create an mdx tag in the new documentation site: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/mdx/commit

Answer (score 3):

The query you've posted has the following errors:

```
select [full name] from (
select customers.[full name].members on rows,
salesman.id.members on columns,
measures.amount on pages
from [Analysis Services Test]
) as test;
```

1. An alias at the end `as test`
2. You've not specified an axes in this section `select [full name] from (`
3. You're using `customers` whereas in the screenshot I can only see `Customer`
4. In the screenshot I cannot see `[full name]` so I will change to `[Customer].[id]`

Try it like this:

```
SELECT 
   [Customer].[Id].[Id].members ON 0,
   [measures].[amount] ON 1 
FROM(
  SELECT 
    [Customer].[Id].[Id].members on 0,
    [Salesman].[Id].[Id].members on 1,
    [Measures].[Amount] on 2
  FROM [Analysis Services Test]
);
```

The above (once working!) won't really do much so try being specific in the subselect:

```
SELECT 
   [Customer].[Id].members ON 0,
   [measures].[amount] ON 1 
FROM(
  SELECT 
    [Customer].[Id].[Id].[whytheq] on 0,
    [Salesman].[Id].[Id].[Ian] on 1,
    [Measures].[Amount] on 2
  FROM [Analysis Services Test]
);
```

---

note

But why worry about pages and sections? There isn't much documentation out there about them because they are not used.

Even with just two dimensions things can get quite complicated, quite quickly. There are plenty of examples out there, take this script of Chris Webb's:

```
WITH
MEMBER MEASURES.[Returning Customers] AS
COUNT(
NONEMPTY(
NONEMPTY(
[Customer].[Customer].[Customer].MEMBERS
, [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount])
, {[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]}
* {NULL : [Date].[Calendar].CURRENTMEMBER.PREVMEMBER}
)
)
MEMBER MEASURES.[New Customers] AS
[Measures].[Customer Count] – MEASURES.[Returning Customers]
SELECT
{[Measures].[Customer Count]
, MEASURES.[Returning Customers]
, MEASURES.[New Customers]} ON 0,
[Date].[Calendar].[Calendar Year].MEMBERS ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

https://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/?s=mdx+new+and+returning

Comment: Thanks for posting.  The first error I got was: "'[customers]' was not found in the cube when the string", so I corrected that, then: '[customers]' was not found in the cube when the string", so I corrected that, then "'[Sales Amount]' was not found in the cube when the string", so I corrected that.  Now it says: "" Query (6, 5) The MEMBERS function expects a hierarchy expression for the  argument. A member expression was used.

Comment: I changed to the names you have used.

Comment: Thanks.  I tried your second query.  The response was: "The dimension '[customers]' was not found in the cube when the string, [customers].[full name], was parsed."  I corrected this.  Now the error is: "uery (6, 5) The MEMBERS function expects a hierarchy expression for the  argument. A member expression was used."

Comment: According to the screenshot it is Customer not Customers. I changed my script. What will be more fun is if you expand Customer and Salesman and use specific members in the subselect - I do not know what the Ids in your cube are so let me make some up - you can replace with actual values

Comment: Thanks, that has worked.  Is there ever a scenario where a derived table like this would be useful? I cannot think of one.

Comment: Yes there is a definite use case for subselects - if you have a situation where you want to filter on a hierarchy (i.e. put it in the WHERE clause) but also want to use it on rows or on columns then you get an error - as you're not allowed to use the same hierarchy more than once. So a possible solution is to do the filtering in a subselect - then in the outer query you can use it again.